# How can I mark the damage on wood floors that are to be resurfaced?

Tags: hardwood-floor

During the build process, the flooring (Hickory Wood with a water-based sealer) had some marks.  The marks appear to be from someone getting stain on their shoes.  There are moon shaped spots in quite a few areas.

My builder is coming to resurface the floor tomorrow and I want to mark up the floor in a way he can see them and make sure they are taken care of.  Although the whole floor is going to be resurfaced, I just want to make sure he is aware of all the spots.

What can I use to mark those spots that won't interfere with the sanding or re-sealing processes?

Answer (score 7):

I would just put down some green/blue painters tape around the spots.  This tape has low-adhesion so it is less likely to remove any finish.  Just make sure the builder removes the tape before refinishing.

Comment: And take a picture after you tape but before they start so that you can remember where the marks were.